# Jquery - Context of ajax callbacks not adhering to supplied context argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery plugin which I use to wrap all my ajax calls. It's intended to do some generic pre/post processing of input/output data.

```
(function ($) {
    $.ajaxCall = function () {

        var myCall = this;
        myCall.settings = {};

        myCall.ExecuteService = function (caller) {
            var ajax = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../myWebservice',
                dataType: "json",
                context: caller,
                success: myCall.settings.onSuccess
            });
        };
    };
} (jQuery));
```

My problem is when I try to modify the onSuccess event to be more than a passed in function. I have the following code which makes use of the the plugin.

```
this.foo = 'fooStr';
function myOnSuccess(result) {
    alert(this.foo);
}

var newCall = new $.ajaxCall();
newCall.settings.onSuccess = myOnSuccess;
newCall.ExecuteService(this);

function myProto() {
    this.foo = 'otherFooStr';
}

myProto.prototype.success = function(result){
    alert(this.foo);
}

myProto.prototype.makeCall = function(){
    var newCall = new $.ajaxCall();
    newCall.settings.onSuccess = this.success;
    newCall.ExecuteService(this);
}

var proto = new myProto();
proto.makeCall();
```

This displays 'fooStr' & 'otherFooStr', and appears to be working fine. But if I try to modify my plugin to do more in the success callback, I have context issues.

```
myCall.ExecuteService = function (caller) {
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../myWebservice',
        dataType: "json",
        context: caller,
    });
    ajax.success(function(result,status,xhr){
        //*Do some processing to find condition*
        if (condition) {
        //myCall.settings.onSuccess(result); //shows 'undefined' & 'undefined'
        //eval(myCall.settings.onSuccess)(result); //shows 'fooStr' & 'fooStr'
        //this.eval(myCall.settings.onSuccess)(result); //shows 'fooStr' & throws an object exception
        }
    });
};
```

The context of the success callback is correct, but it seems to lose it once the onSuccess functions are called. Am I going about this the correct way?

Comment: At a first sight I think you need to use call(), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: call() worked perfectly, thanks. If you would be so good as to post that as the answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `call()` to pass the right context to the `onSuccess` function, like

```
myCall.settings.onSuccess.call(<your context, e.g. this>, result)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call